# How do I include a resource in a Sightly template only if it exists?

Tags: sling, sightly

I would like to use `data-sly-resource` to include a resource, but only if it exists, e.g.

```html
<div class="pull-right" data-sly-resource="/content/blog/stats"></div>
```

If the resource does not exist the script execution fails with the following error message: Cannot find servlet to handle resource /content/blog/stats . From the Request Progress listing I can see that it's a `SyntheticResource`:

> TIMER_START{resolveServlet(SyntheticResource, type=null, path=/content/blog/stats)}

How can I include the resource conditionally, only if it exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the best solution would be to allow your `redis/stats` component to correctly handle the situation when a `Resource` it's supposed to render is a `SyntheticResource` or, more generally, doesn't provide any properties.

Therefore the calling Sightly snippet should be:

```
<div class="pull-right" data-sly-resource="${'/content/blog/stats' @ resourceType='redis/stats'}"></div>
```

This forces the rendering to be made by your `redis/stats` component, even if the `/content/blog/stats` resource doesn't exist (well, Sling will return a `SyntheticResource`, like you mentioned).

In your `redis/stats` component you could then try this safeguard:

```
<div class="blog-stats" data-sly-test="${properties}">
<!--/* This whole block will only be rendered if properties is not empty */-->
</div>
```

which would render the `div.blog-stats` only if the properties map was not empty [0].

[0] - https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/1.1/SPECIFICATION.md#225-test

Answer (score 2):

**If** the resource you need to include  (e.g. `stats`) is a child of the current resource, then this might work:

```xml
<div data-sly-test="${resource['stats/jcr:primaryType']}"
    class="pull-right" 
    data-sly-resource="stats"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement a use script which tests for the existence of the resource:

**stats.js**:

```
use(function () {

    var hasStats = false;
    var stats = resource.getResourceResolver().getResource('/content/blog/stats');
    if ( stats != null && stats.getResourceType() == "redis/stats" ) {
        hasStats = true;
    } 

    return {
        hasStats: hasStats
    }
});
```

**page.html**:

```
<sly data-sly-use.stats="stats.js"/>

<div data-sly-test="${stats.hasStats}" class="pull-right" data-sly-resource="/content/blog/stats"></div>
```

This has the disadvantage of requiring a use script, hopefully there is a simpler way.